# mysql vb.net There is already an open Data Reader associated with this connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've already added reader.dispose() but it's still showing the exception

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection which must be closed first.

Please don't mind the Sql injection. I'll be fixing that soon.

```
Private Sub ItemStore(ByVal itemname)
        mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
        mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=sdudb"
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        Try
            mydbcon.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from inventory where itemname = '" & itemname & "'"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
            reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read
                AddItemstoDatabase(reader.GetString("itemcategory"), reader.GetString("itemname"), reader.GetString("price"), reader.GetString("stockcount"))
            End While
            reader.Close()
            reader.Dispose()
            mydbcon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddItemstoDatabase(ByVal itemcategory, ByVal itemname, ByVal price, ByVal stock)
        mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
        mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=sdudb"
        Try
            mydbcon.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "INSERT into itemstored(itemcategory, itemname, price, stockcount) VALUES('" & itemcategory & "', '" & itemname & "', '" & price & "', '" & stock & "')"
            Dim rowsadded = COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If rowsadded = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to update database")
            End If
            mydbcon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe where exactly your exception is raised like described in the help center. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix it by adding

```
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
```

between the query and the `COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Thank you all for the other answers!

Answer (score 2):

Since your method `ItemStore` have already open connection for same connection string, and from same method again you calling another function `AddItemstoDatabase` which is also going to use same connection string.
Due to this reason you are getting this exception

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection which must be closed first.

And you can't open multiple connection for same connection string without closing earlier open connection .

**UPDATE**
Not sure if it works in your scenario, try comment connection obj since it is global

```
Private Sub AddItemstoDatabase(ByVal itemcategory, ByVal itemname, ByVal price, ByVal stock)
    'mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
    'mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=sdudb"
    Try
        'mydbcon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "INSERT into itemstored(itemcategory, itemname, price, stockcount) VALUES('" & itemcategory & "', '" & itemname & "', '" & price & "', '" & stock & "')"
        COMMAND.CommandText = Query 
        Dim rowsadded = COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If rowsadded = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to update database")
        End If
        'mydbcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: what's the get around for that?

Comment: I Updated Ans try It

Comment: Well it says now that "Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property while the connection (state=Open)."

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
```

to:

```
Dim mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
```

and it will work.

You are using a globally declared connection variable there.
And as the error states, you can't have 2 data readers open in 1 connection at the same time.

Comment: and while you are at it, move the connection closing code to a finally block.  You are going to encounter situations where an error causes the code to jump to the catch block, leaving the connections open.